Cloud Functions: Can't see function logs in function explorer
When I deployed my Cloud Functions previously I could see the logs and everything in the logs explorer. However, there were some errors and upon some research, I found that in order to get my queue in the functions I have to create it Cloud Functions SDK. So I downloaded it. The installation requires Python so I downloaded it as well. I created my queue Id successfully and I placed it in my functions.
However, after all these, when I deploy a function, I don't see my logs in the logs explorer anymore. The terminal tells me the deploy complete. I see the deployed functions in the Firebase Console, but when I click on view logs, I don't see the deployed logs.
Even when I go to "Recent" on my log explorer, I see the functions there. But when I click on it I don't see any log.

....................................................................

I use firebase deploy --only functions:FUNCTIONS_NAME to deploy my functions.
I'm using JavaScript
My code
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.taskCallback = functions.https
    .onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      const {UID} = req.body;
      const docRef = database.collection("ADSGHANA").doc(UID);
      const doc = await docRef.get();
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log(`Document with UID ${UID} does not exist.`);
        res.status(404).send("Document not found.");
        return;
      }

      const {TimestampDeparture, PostStatus} = doc.data();
      const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
      if (now == TimestampDeparture && PostStatus !== "Cancelled") {
        await docRef.update({PostStatus: "Started"});
        console.log(`Post with UID ${UID} has been started.`);
        res.status(200).send("Post started successfully.");
      } else {
        console.log(`Post with UID ${UID} is not ready to start.`);
        res.status(200).send("Post not ready to start yet.");
      }
    });

exports.scheduledTask = functions.firestore.document("ADSGHANA/{UID}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      const {UID, TimestampDeparture} = data;
      const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
      if (now == TimestampDeparture) {
        console.log(`Post with UID ${UID} should have already started.`);
        return null;
      }
      const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;
      const location = "us-central1";
      const queue = "scheduleAds";
      const task = {
        httpRequest: {
          httpMethod: "POST",
          url: `https://${location}/${project}.cloudfunctions.net/taskCallback?UID=${UID}`,
          body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({UID})).toString("base64"),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        },
        scheduleTime: TimestampDeparture,

      };
      const {CloudTasksClient} = require("@google-cloud/tasks");
      const client = new CloudTasksClient();
      const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);
      const [response] = await client.createTask({parent, task});
      console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);
      return null;
    });


Have you tried these troubleshooting steps? Are you able to see logs for other functions?

I tried to replicate by following basic deployment with your code and I can able to see logs. Can you share the steps you are following?

Ok, I will try troubleshooting later

update here once you have tried troubleshooting doc

I tried again this morning without touching anything and now I can view the log again
